# Stanford CoreNLP: output in CONLL format from Java

Tags: format, dependencies, stanford-nlp

I want to parse some German text with Stanford CoreNLP and obtain a CONLL output, so that I can pass the latter to CorZu for coreference resolution.

How can I do that *programmatically*?

Here is my code so far (which only outputs dependency trees):

```
Annotation germanAnnotation = new Annotation("Gestern habe ich eine blonde Frau getroffen");
Properties germanProperties = StringUtils.argsToProperties("-props", "StanfordCoreNLP-german.properties");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(germanProperties);
pipeline.annotate(germanAnnotation);

StringBuilder trees = new StringBuilder("");
for (CoreMap sentence : germanAnnotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
     Tree sentenceTree = sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
     trees.append(sentenceTree).append("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following code I managed to save the parsing output in CONLL format.

```
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("./target/", OUTPUT_FILE_NAME));
CoNLLOutputter.conllPrint(germanAnnotation, outputStream, pipeline);
```

However, the HEAD field was 0 for all words. I am not sure whether there is a problem in parsing or only in the CONLLOutputter. Honestly, I was too annoyed by CoreNLP to investigate further.

I decided and I suggest using ParZu instead. [ParZu](https://github.com/rsennrich/ParZu/blob/master/README.md) and [CorZu](http://www.cl.uzh.ch/en/research/completed-research/coreferenceresolution.html) are made to work together seamlessly - and they do.
In my case, I had an already tokenized and POS tagged text. This makes things easier, since you will **not** need:

- A POS-Tagger using the STTS tagset
- A tool for morphological analysis

Once you have ParZu and CorZu installed, you will only need to run `corzu.sh` (included in the CorZu download folder). If your text is tokenized and POS tagged, you can edit the script accordingly:

```
parzu_cmd="/YourPath/ParZu/parzu -i tagged"
```

Last note: make sure to convert your tagged text to the following format, with empty lines signifying sentence boundaries: word [tab] tag [newline]